# Npgsql used from powershell - is there limit on command length?

Tags: npgsql

I read sql script from file, it has multiple commands in it and its size is currently 33171 bytes
i put in into CommandText and verified that it is complete

then i run $command.ExecuteNonQuery() and i get exception with syntax error at end of input POSITION: 30577

but script itself is valid, i can run it as batch for example in HeidiSQL without any problems
it seems that postgresql didn't get complete command, can I somehow force it to start processing only when it is completed?

```
        $connection = New-Object Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = "$connectionStringWithoutDatabase;Database=$($d)"
        $connection.Open()

        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $q
        $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
        $command.CommandTimeout = 0
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I got

```
Debug: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "42601: syntax error at end of input

POSITION: 30577"
 ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at end of input
```